# Cmake: link to iOS library

Tags: ios, cmake

I've a CMake toolchain that should generate static library to deploy in a suitable client app for a selected platform. Available platform is for now only the iOS, however after running CMake and generate the project (both projects: static library and client are build correctly), Xcode fails to build during the linking process. Strange fact, it's not linking also against basic libraries like “std”.

Here the linking issue:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "typeinfo for std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>", referenced from:
      typeinfo for boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet in boost(utf8_codecvt_facet.o)
  "std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t>::~codecvt()", referenced from:
      boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet::~utf8_codecvt_facet() in boost(utf8_codecvt_facet.o)
      boost::filesystem::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet::~utf8_codecvt_facet() in boost(utf8_codecvt_facet.o)
  "VTT for std::istream", referenced from:
      boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::toi(char const*&, char const*, int) const in boost(instances.o)
  "std::numpunct<char>::id", referenced from:
      boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::toi(char const*&, char const*, int) const in boost(instances.o)
```

I have created the cmake project as in this [sample](https://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/wiki/HowTo)

somebody has a clue?

Comment: So do you have a build of boost for iOS (which will have to be a "fat library" of armv6, armv7, armv7s and i386 architectures)?

Comment: Not 100% sure about this, but maybe you are just missing the `-stdlib=libc++` compile option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all,

I solved by just adding the flag "-stdlib=libc++"(as ComicSansMS suggested, thanks) and command include_directories(${Boost_DIR}) to CMakeLists.txt

thanks
Roberto